# How to hide Navigation Controller in Root View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, xcode5

Please, help me to hide navigation controller in root view. I've found the solution to write `[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]` in every view controller which I need. Well, it works but only for the first time: I run application, in root view I don't have navigation, then I go to the second view – the navigation appears, OK. But then I press "Back" in navigation controller, and navigation from root view hasn't disappear. I work with xib.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In rootViewController

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

In second View(next to rootViewController)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

Use this line of code on all your view controllers

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];
```

If no animation is needed you can do animated:NO and add this code in viewDidLoad or put it viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

In your case

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

on your rootViewController, 
and

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

on your other viewControllers

Answer (score 0):

Hide Navigation bar all view controller's view will appear method.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 [navigationCOntroller setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using tab bar controller.

Your code is working for first view controller as you have code there only. For second view controller, it goes default and hence for second view controller you see navigation bar.

To hide navigation bar for all view controller, put hidden code in all view controllers viewWillAppear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: looks like it took you the longest to write this :)

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift** developers

**Swift 4.2**

*RootViewController.swift*

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
}
```

*NextViewController.swift*

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```