# Hide UINavigationbar and yet show Status bar on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to hide UINavigation Bar and only show Status bar for the Rootview controller.
this.NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, true);

hides both. now it look like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TDjI.png) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Status Bar](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/status-bars/):

[image]

[Navigation Bar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar):

[image]

**So, your screenshot shows the Status Bar and didn't show the Navigation Bar. The code works fine as you expected.**

For more details on how to hide/show Status Bar and Navigation Bar, please see the below section:

1. To hide/show Status Bar you need to add this setting in your info.plist file:

   ```
   <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
   <false />
   ```

   Then add the code in your ViewController:

   ```
   UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarHidden(true/false,true);
   ```
2. To hide/show the Navigation Bar, you just need to add the codes in `ViewWillAppear`:

   ```
   this.NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true/false, true);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, 
Adding both the lines to hide and show in the ViewwillAppear() did the trick .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation.

From your attached picture & question to hide UINavigationBar & only show Status Bar, it looks like it is correct & your code is correct too.

Attached is answer maybe you looking for: [How to hide Navigation Controller in Root View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421962/how-to-hide-navigation-controller-in-root-view)

Answer (score 0):

First check that in the file info.plist

[image]

Verify that Hide status bar is not checked. If you want to show the status bar.

[image]

and let me know if solve your problem.

Comment: I solved it by adding two lines this.NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, true);
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarHidden(false, true); in the ViewWillAppear() and setting it in the .plist like the accepted answer